# Using (Delphi + Intraweb) how to force logout from that session while using IWAutherEvent,?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

After checking the demo [Authentication](https://github.com/Atozed/IntraWeb/tree/master/XIV/Delphi/Authentication) on github.com I thought to give it a try and it's working fine, however the session is kept a live!

how to force logout from the user session?

also, how to clear whatever related in the browser session/cookies? I tried to clear it manually by normal ways, but it never works. the session keeps returning!

I tried to terminate the session or release the form nothing appears to force the user to logout!

so anyway to force logout?